# link sharepoint 2007 list to current user login

Tags: listview, sharepoint-2007

I have a list which allows a user to enter data into columns.  One of the columns is their email address.  I want to return only those records for which the current user's email address is the same as the user who is logged in?  Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Creating a view to "see only their items" wont work?

Comment: Did not work based on email address.  I had to create a column called Assign, and that allowed the webpart to differnetiate based on login.